# SELECT statement not working right

Tags: php, sql, database, select

I'm using this code to retrieve data from a table I created.

```
SELECT id,shirt_name,boys FROM shirts WHERE boys IS NOT NULL
```

Instead of just selecting the rows where the boys column has input, it selects all of them.  here's the way I created the table

```
CREATE TABLE shirts (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    shirt_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    men VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    women VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    boys VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    girls VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    babies VARCHAR(10) NULL,
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO shirts(shirt_name,men,women,boys,girls,babies) VALUES
    ('Crewneck Tee','me_crn','wo_crn','bo_crn','gi_crn','ba_crn'),
    ('V-Neck Tee','me_vnc','wo_vnc','','',''),
    ('Scoop Neck Tee','','wo_sco','','',''),
    ('Raglan Tee','me_rag','wo_rag','bo_rag','gi_rag',''),
    ('Ringer Tee','me_rin','wo_rin','bo_rin','gi_rin',''),
    ('Cap Sleeve Tee','','wo_cap','','gi_cap',''),
    ('Tank Top','me_tan','wo_tan','bo_tan','gi_tan',''),
    ('Spaghetti Strap','','wo_spa','','',''),
    ('Hoodie','me_hod','wo_hod','bo_hod','gi_hod','ba_hod');
```

what did I do wrong?

Comment: non-empty string (i.e. spaces) in column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id,shirt_name,boys FROM shirts WHERE boys != ''
```

Is what you need to use with this data

Comment: In this case, especially given the data model, I'd say they should fix their data, not the statement.

Answer (score 4):

You did not insert any records with `NULL` in the `boys` column. Only records where it's an empty string. And an empty string (`''`) is different from `NULL`, so it matches `IS NOT NULL`.